# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

when I create google map and run, it says java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList on logcat

Answer (score 2):

change google play service version in Gradle dependencies bellow 10.4.0
like compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' or compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
}
```

or

```
 dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
```

}

Comment: Welcome @DharmendraMishra

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
}
```

**If you need only map then compile the dependency of map only.Do not compile complete google play service dependency.**